# Redirect to HTTPS and rewrite to local app in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https, url-rewriting

I have a node.js app on a VPS. The only way my VPS provider allow to use node.js is creating an .htaccess file with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```

I don't access site from localhost, but from public accessible domain - like http://example.com.

If I use rules above It's works as expected. But I also need to redirect all trafic to HTTPS. So I made made these changes:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```

But what I got is the exact behaviour as the previous rule. It's redirecting trafic to localhost, but it doesn't force the browser to use HTTPS.

Please do anyone knows where's the problem? Thank for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8080/$1 [P]
```

Comment: Could you share which hosting it is? I believe it is their quirk to not parse the whole htaccess, but just look for the localhost proxy to make node.js work. Could you try any other .httaccess rule and see if it works?

Comment: Well, The provider is http://www.savana.cz/, it's just simple php hosting on regular ubuntu VPS, to which I have ssh access. I don't even have an root access. But throw that I control npm ad node.